# I got Validating My Version of Xcode status as "rejected"

Tags: xcode, validation, version, xcode6.1.1

I validating my version of Xcode in Terminal using this command

spctl --assess --verbose /Applications/Xcode.app

with reference of https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a

i got the below status for my Xcode.

[image]

in my Macbook i have 4 versions of Xcode's in that lastest version is 6.1.1 named as (Xcode.app) are there can any one help me is there

Comment: Did you download Xcode from the Apple developer site or did you get it from some random download site ?

Comment: @PaulR Don't know previously my Macbook is used by some other person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download latest version Xcode 7 from mac app stor and check validate

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall Xcode & download from app store